Vertx Thread Blocked Confusion
As far as I understand, in Vertx, there are two separate thread pools. The event loop threads and the worker threads.
I have a code like this
//subscriber sample code 
eventBus.send(ADDRESS_1, message, response -> {
    //response logic
})

And I have a code to receive the it under which I have some blocking operation.
//consumer sample code
eventBus.consumer(ADDRESS_1, message -> { 
    //blocking operation here
    awss3.list()
})

The issue with this is I am getting thread blocked on both my event loop and worker threads. Shouldn't Vertx delegate the workflow of the consumer part to worker threads? If yes, then how is it causing thread blocked issue in the event loop itself?
Edit:
I have set the following deployment options in the while deploying the verticles:
DeploymentOptions opt = new DeploymentOptions();
opt.setWorker(true);


Default vertx uses event-loop. In your code, blocking operation blocks event-loop. Don't do that.
Please read:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#blocking_code
Update:
Worker Verticles: These run using a thread from the worker pool. An instance is never executed concurrently by more than one thread. The thread can be blocked by a blocking operation.
Worker verticle fits to simple single task, not fit to handle event-bus. Let's use ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP with Virtual Thread or use vertx.executeBlocking or declare new executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("worker-pool") for event-bus that has blocking operations

As at here: https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticle_types Worker pool is only used with DeploymentOptions. Does your code declare it ?

I don't understand why you added a comment to your answer. If the comment is part of the answer then it should be added to the text of the answer.

I am a new member. Just test a comment. Thank u

I have set setWorker(true) while deploying the verticles

Hey @aryakdangol, the document of vertx writes: Worker Verticles: These run using a thread from the worker pool. An instance is never executed concurrently by more than one thread. The thread can be blocked by a blocking operation. Worker verticle doesn't fit to your purpose. Let's use ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP with Virtual Thread or use vertx.executeBlocking or declare new executor = vertx.createSharedWorkerExecutor("worker-pool")

Let's use type Worker Verticle for simple tasks as batch sync data, send email v.v..... We can shutdown verticle after completing task. Not for tasks as: HttpServer, Event-Bus

AFAIK, the EventBus runs on the Event Loop only.
That means, you shall under no circumstances block it.
That means in turn, that the Consumer does NOT do any magic out-of-box to turn your blocking code into a non-blocking one.
With that said, the consumer impl might look like so:
eventBus.consumer(ADDRESS_1, message -> { 
  Future.future( prom -> { 
    try{
      prom.complete( awss3.list() );
    }catch( Exception e ){
      prom.fail( e );
    }    
  } ).onComplete( asyncRes -> {
     if( asyncRes.succeeded() ) 
       message.reply( asyncRes.result() );
     else 
       message.fail( 400, asyncRes.cause().getMessage() );
  } );    
} )


Actually, I wrote a very short form. We are converting the consumer to an Observable
